# Facebook Connect application inside iframe not working in IE7

Tags: cookies, facebook

I am building a Facebook Connect application that runs inside a Google gadget. Being a gadget means that the application runs inside an iframe. Inside the application, there is a form that allows registered users to post comments. The submission is made using AJAX, but I get the same results with a normal form. The problem is that I need to get the user's facebook id. In Firefox, it works fine, but on Internet Explorer 7, I get the following error:

```
 'A session key is required for calling this method'
```

I believe that this is due to the way IE handles third-party cookies, because if I go to Internet options / Privacy / Advanced, and check Override automatic cookie handling and accept all cookies, it works fine. I cannot pass the Facebook id from the javascript, because anyone could tamper it.

EDIT: If I open the content of the iframe directly, the app works fine. The problem is really due to the IFRAME and IE security model.

What am I doing something wrong? How can I work around this problem?

Comment: I'm hitting a similar problem with a Facebook Connect application that runs inside an overlaid iframe on a third-party site, except I'm having the problem with Safari and Firefox too, if users have opted not to accept third party cookies. Did you see the same issues there, or am I missing something?

Comment: I did not try to block third party cookies on other browsers, but that should cause the same problems. I went for the solution of opening a popup. In fact, Facebook now uses a "fake" popup inside my popup, instead of opening another window, which is ok for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried adding a P3P policy ?

If the response setting the cookie has a compact policy, IE will use this to determine whether or not to allow the 3rd party cookie..

Comment: Hi, I didn't know about that. I will investigate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem by modifying how I check if the user was logged in on the PHP page following a FB connect login.

So, they login to FB Connect with IE7.
Next and subsequent page loads where I need to verify they are indeed logged into FaceBook I used the following code (note that $facebook->require_login() and other functions did not work - they returned null only in IE 7):

`// Validate from Facebook that session is valid and user is logged in. 
    require_once 'facebook/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(YourAppsAPIKeyPublic, YourAppsAPIKeySecret);
    $facebook->api_client->session_key = $this->userAPISessionKey;
    $fb_user_id = $facebook->api_client->users_getLoggedInUser();`

The $fb_user_id should now have a valid FaceBook user ID.

## Regarding privacy policy and facebook connect  + IE 7:

Although this didn't work for me it appears to work for others. in HTAccess:

`Header append P3P "CP=\"HONK\""`

or in PHP files:

`header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');` 
or
`header('P3P: CP="HONK"');`

reference: http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=28636

ASP.NET:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");
}
```

Comment: in your code, you use "$this->userAPISessionKey", so what object is referenced by "this"?? thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around that works, although it is a bit ugly: when the user clicks the 'login' button, it opens a popup that comes from my own site and which contains the Facebook Connect login button. After the user logs in, I close the popup and reload the iframe.

This is really ugly because It opens two popups, but at least it works. I will detect whether cookies are enabled using javascript and if they are enabled, I will skip the first popup.

I'm still open to better solutions...

---

**Edit**: Facebook now uses a "fake" popup inside my popup, instead of opening another window. Now I only have one popup which is ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to see this thread also, which is created under facebook developer platform

http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=452